# will outlook tasks be included in the graph api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

The obvious exclusion from the MS Graph api is outlook tasks.

Given that the me/tasks resource returns planner tasks and not outlook tasks one could speculate that there are no plans to ever include outlook tasks. Is this correct?

Should we read anything into this re the future of Outlook Tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will. We are actively working on this and will be included in an upcoming release. Stay tuned.

Comment: Are there any updates on this one? Where can we follow the progress, GitHub? It's been almost a year and Tasks is still not out of Beta?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [To Do API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/todo-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) to get Outlook tasks from Microsoft Graph.

*Note 1: there still is the [Outlook tasks API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/outlooktask?view=graph-rest-beta), but it has been deprecated and will be defunct as of August 2022.*

*Note 2: the To Do API currently returns less information about tasks than the Outlook tasks API :(*